# Allow only a-Z, 0-9 using preg_match, preg_replace

Tags: preg-replace, preg-match

Could somebody please help out with this line? How to modify it so it only allows a-Z, 0-9?
Thanks.

> ```
>     if (preg_match('~[<>&"\'=\\\]~', preg_replace('~&#(?:\\d{1,7}|x[0-9a-fA-F]{1,6});~', '', $context['checked_username'])) != 0 || $context['checked_username'] == '_' || $context['checked_username'] == '|' || strpos($context['checked_username'], '[code') !== false || strpos($context['checked_username'], '[/code') !== false)
>             $context['valid_username'] = false;
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following code checks [[:alnum:]] (`alnum` stands for alpha numeric)

```
if (!preg_match("/^[[:alnum:]]+$/", $context['checked_username']))
{
    $context['valid_username'] = false;
}
```